# Ambiguity with constructing objects

Tags: c++

Here is an example I wrote up:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(int)
  {

  };
};

int main()
{
  int baz = 10;
  Foo(1); // OK
  Foo(baz); // Fails, redefinition 
  return 0;
}
```

Why does `Foo(baz)` try construct a new object `baz`, rather than constructing an anonymous object passing an argument `baz` to the constructor? When I declare an object `bar` by writing `Foo(bar)`, I get a default initialized object just fine, but once I try passing a argument, it fails. How is the ambiguity resolved?

Comment: If it could be a declaration, it is a declaration.

Comment: @melpomene why it can't be a declaration with a literal, but it can be a declaration with a variable (without a type)?

Comment: What do you mean, without a type? `Foo` is a type. It can't be a declaration with `1` because `1` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: I assume this is related to the most vexing parse. But not how I have seen it manifest before. I suppose `baz` must be seen as an undeclared type...? I don't know why that would be though.

Comment: Ooh, I thought that it's actually most vexing parse problem, but it's just a variable name reuse? Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

`Foo(baz);` is equivalent to `Foo baz;` which is obviously a declaration.

And as `baz` was already declared as a local variable of type `int` earlier in the *same scope*, you get a redefinition-error.

Comment: This is evidently correct but I still don't see why declarations like that are allowed. Do you know if there is  any use for that kind of declaration?

Comment: @Galik Mix pointers, functions, and arrays, stir rigorously, and you might need parentheses for overriding the natural grouping. For simple declarations, yes, it obviously only leads to Irritation.

Comment: @Galik This specific form? No, but declarators are parsed like expressions and you need the parens e.g. in `int (*ptr)[10];`. It's just that `int (*ptr);` and `int (i);` are also valid.

Comment: @Galik: it's probably tied to how parenthesis are tied to complex declarations:  [`int (*(*foo)(char))(short)`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*%28*foo%29%28char%29%29%28short%29)

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course. It is easier to allow this to facilitate the "right-left" rule of determining types. This is what it boils down to at the simplest level.